# diver.findElements gets hanged in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
int editBtnCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("abc")).size();
```

My program gets stuck at the aboove code when there is no such element identified through the xpath  `By.xpath("abc")`. So it should return 0 right? But it hangs.

Comment: `findElements` waits for at least one element or until timeout which is defined by the implicit wait setting.

Comment: `.findElement()` alone does no waiting so if there is a pause, it's most likely that somewhere in your script framework an implicit wait is set.

Comment: Sorry? .findelement waits right? And findelements do not wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`driver.findElement(By loc)` and `driver.findElements(By loc)`, both the methods are affected by the `implicit wait` times. So both methods will return a matching element/elements, or try again repeatedly until the configured timeout is reached.
So if your script gets stuck, it is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with Try-catch approach, if there is no such element. So script will be not continue of after Exception without Hang.

```
try
{
int editBtnCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("abc")).size();
}  catch (Exception e) 
   {
   System.out.println("Element not find");
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

So here in try, it will try to find elements and if there is not single it will go for catch block. And execution will be continue. In catch, you can pass user define message also.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation [**`findElements()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method finds all the elements within the current page using the mechanism provided. This method is affected by the timeframe configured through **implicitlyWait** or **explicitlyWait** at the time of execution. When *implicitly* or *explicitly* waiting, this method will return as soon as there are **more than 0** items in the found *collection* or will return an *empty list* if the **timeout** is reached.

I made a small test with your line of code as follows :

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.id("automaticSoldier")).size());
driver.quit();
```

It correctly prints the following in the console :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9027c746edd3201443e011a61ed) on port 7531
Only local connections are allowed.
May 04, 2018 1:32:28 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
0
```

But as you find that the program hangs the main suspicion is as :

- You have configured `implicitlyWait()` and *WebDriver* instance is waiting.

### Additional Considerations

For a better [**`Test Harness`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_harness) follow the below steps :

- Replace the instance of `implicitlyWait()` with instances of `explicitlyWait()` i.e. `WebDriverWait()` whereever required.
- Do not mix `implicitlyWait()` and `explicitlyWait()`. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u162**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u162-relnotes-4021436.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.11.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *WebDriver* variant to current levels. [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) / [**GeckoDriver v0.20.1**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
- Upgrade *WebClient* variant (i.e *Firefox*, *Chrome*, *IE*, *Edge*, *Safari*) to current levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Hang is not a suitable word for it, may be you wanna call it wait for some specific time which you must have defined in your script.[Implicit wait I'm talking about].

your **code**

```
int editBtnCount=driver.findElements(By.xpath("abc")).size();
```

Will wait for **elements** with **xpath** "abc" till the time implicit wait is declared.

If elements are found then `.size()` method will return the count.

else **0** would be returned with no **exceptions**.